# get current user email that is logged

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase to do the authentication in my application, and everything works fine, but when i log in i want to display the user email that is logged in, and what i did crashes the application when i run it, so i did this:

```
 auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  userTxt.setText(auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().toString());
```

i defined a auth object and then used that auth to get the current user email, after that all in one line i passed that to my textView, what am i doing wrong here?

**StackTrace**

```
04-09 09:00:11.247 2987-2987/com.esmad.pdm.friendlymanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.esmad.pdm.friendlymanager, PID: 2987
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.esmad.pdm.friendlymanager/com.esmad.pdm.friendlymanager.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.esmad.pdm.friendlymanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: The [logcat will tell you the reason your app has stopped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this). Please [edit] your question with it.

Comment: I see two opportunities for NullPointer here. 1) No current user 2) No email

Comment: Make sure you have downloaded `google-services.json` file from [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)

Comment: i did, just a question, do i need to place it inside the app folder or outside?

Answer (score 1):

Your logcat is giving you the answer:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null
>   object reference

so your invoking `getCurrentUser()` on a null object.

extra:

I have just come upon another situation where the user's **email** would return **null** even if you have correctly initialized your `FirebaseUser`

There's a [closed bug report](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/266) already filed with google:

> When you go to the **Auth > Sign-In Methods** page of your project in the Firebase console. do you have **One account per email address** on or off? If you allow multiple accounts per email address, **you will get null** for FirebaseUser.**getEmail()**

[image]

You have to use the option: "Prevent creation of multiple accounts with the same email address" or else **FirebaseUser.getEmail() will return null**

Ps: only users who first logged in after the option was turned off will be able to use this method successfully

Answer (score 0):

it crash because `getCurrentUser()` might return `null`

try this

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser theUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (theUser !=null)
    String _UID = theUser.getEmail().toString();
```

and I prefer to use `AuthStateListener`

In `MainActivity`

```
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
```

then in `onCreate`

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    String _UID = Theuser.getUid();
                    String Uemail= Theuser..getEmail().toString();
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                }
            }
        };
```

and in `onStart`

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
      mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}
```

and in **onStop**

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain me better why you need that 2 lines at onStart and onStop, i don't get it why there is a nullpointerexception, if i just open that activity if i have a user, else i open a registration, if i remove my 2 lines it enters the homepage, that means it has a user :S, i checked that before

Comment: a little late but i can answer to that, you just use  mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener); in the onStart because when the MainActivity or your Activity where you are checking if the user exists to do something, so, when the app just starts it will check if the user is != null, so it will tell to you if there is an user logged in, and will start listening whenever the user is != null or == to null. as onStop goes it says that if the user is still loggedd in it will remove the listener that is listening about the user state.